# jQuery: the checked property is undefined on change event

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onchange

I see many questions on this topic but none have resolved my issue.

**Trouble is:** I have a checkbox and need the new value of the checked property when a user clicks it.

I have tried the different event attachers like on.("change" .. and .change(function() .. but always it returns "undefined". 
I have also tested (with alerts) if the assignment to the variables was done more then once, but they dont. Just once.

Please consider the script and tell me if you know what I am doing wrong. Or if i should post more info.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#invoice_list :checkbox').on('change', function () {
            var _invoice_id;
            var _payed;
            var _sent;
            $(this).parent().siblings().each(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('name?ajax_invoice_id')) {
                    _invoice_id = $(this).text();
                }
                if ($(this).hasClass('name?ajax_payed')) {
                    _payed = $(this).children(':checkbox').prop('checked');
                }
                if ($(this).hasClass('name?ajax_sent')) {
                    _sent = $(this).children(':checkbox').prop('checked');
                }
            });
            alert('invoice_id: ' + _invoice_id + '\r\npayed: ' + _payed + '\r\nsent: ' + _sent);
        });
    });
```

If i check the "payed" checkbox this is the result no matter the new value (same goes for "sent"): [localhost says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Iac.png)

[html from razor view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFYKx.png)

```
<tbody class="clickable">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="name?ajax_invoice_id">85</td>
                        <td>31-10-2015 16:54:27</td>
                        <td>31-10-2015 00:00:00</td>
                        <td>31-10-2015 00:00:00</td>
                        <td>4800,00</td>
                        <td>6000,00</td>
                        <td>1200,00</td>
                        <td>25,00 %</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>6,00</td>
                        <td>800,00</td>                            
                        <td class="name?ajax_sent"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Sendt field is required." id="Collection_0__Sent" name="Collection[0].Sent" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Collection[0].Sent" type="hidden" value="false" /></td>
                        <td class="name?ajax_payed"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Betalt field is required." id="Collection_0__Payed" name="Collection[0].Payed" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Collection[0].Payed" type="hidden" value="false" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="name?ajax_invoice_id">36</td>
                        <td>25-10-2015 18:54:35</td>
                        <td>25-10-2015 00:00:00</td>
                        <td>25-10-2015 00:00:00</td>
                        <td>6400,00</td>
                        <td>8000,00</td>
                        <td>1600,00</td>
                        <td>25,00 %</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>8,00</td>
                        <td>800,00</td>                            
                        <td class="name?ajax_sent"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Sendt field is required." id="Collection_1__Sent" name="Collection[1].Sent" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Collection[1].Sent" type="hidden" value="false" /></td>
                        <td class="name?ajax_payed"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Betalt field is required." id="Collection_1__Payed" name="Collection[1].Payed" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Collection[1].Payed" type="hidden" value="false" /></td>
                    </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Change `$('#invoice_list :checkbox')` to `$('#invoice_list input[type=checkbox]')`

Comment: @MehdiDehghani just tried that but it's still the same messagebox :-/

Comment: Please show the `html`

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I have posted a screenprint of the html.

Comment: Replace all `:checkbox` with `input[type=checkbox]`, then tell me which one is `undefined` of  this values invoice_id, _payed, _sent

Comment: @MehdiDehghani i changed them all but its still undefined on the one i check. _payed is undefined and _sent is correct when i click the payed input. and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

```
$('table input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  var _invoice_id = 'not found',
    _payed = 'not found',
    _sent = 'not found',
    $this = $(this);

  $this.closest('tr').children('td').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('name?ajax_invoice_id')) {
      _invoice_id = $(this).text();
    }
    if ($this.hasClass('name?ajax_payed')) {
      _payed = $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');
    }
    if ($this.hasClass('name?ajax_sent')) {
      _sent = $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');
    }
  });

  alert('invoice_id: ' + _invoice_id + '\r\npayed: ' + _payed + '\r\nsent: ' + _sent);
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/08gweppo/1/)

Comment: thanks Mehdi but your fiddle is just giving me "not found" on the one i click

Answer (score 1):

To explain your actual issue, `$(this).parent().siblings()` only returns its siblings to the collection and not the `td` which contains the `checkbox` you clicked on.

you can use `.addBack()` which will include the siblings + itself :-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#invoice_list :checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var _invoice_id;
    var _payed;
    var _sent;
    $(this).parent().siblings().addBack().each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('name?ajax_invoice_id')) {
        _invoice_id = $(this).text();
      }
      if ($(this).hasClass('name?ajax_payed')) {
        _payed = $(this).children(':checkbox').prop('checked');
      }
      if ($(this).hasClass('name?ajax_sent')) {
        _sent = $(this).children(':checkbox').prop('checked');
      }
    });
    alert('invoice_id: ' + _invoice_id + '\r\npayed: ' + _payed + '\r\nsent: ' + _sent);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="invoice_list">
  <tbody class="clickable">
    <tr>
      <td class="name?ajax_invoice_id">85</td>
      <td>31-10-2015 16:54:27</td>
      <td>31-10-2015 00:00:00</td>
      <td>31-10-2015 00:00:00</td>
      <td>4800,00</td>
      <td>6000,00</td>
      <td>1200,00</td>
      <td>25,00 %</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>6,00</td>
      <td>800,00</td>
      <td class="name?ajax_sent">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Sendt field is required." id="Collection_0__Sent" name="Collection[0].Sent" type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="Collection[0].Sent" type="hidden" value="false" />
      </td>
      <td class="name?ajax_payed">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Betalt field is required." id="Collection_0__Payed" name="Collection[0].Payed" type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="Collection[0].Payed" type="hidden" value="false" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name?ajax_invoice_id">36</td>
      <td>25-10-2015 18:54:35</td>
      <td>25-10-2015 00:00:00</td>
      <td>25-10-2015 00:00:00</td>
      <td>6400,00</td>
      <td>8000,00</td>
      <td>1600,00</td>
      <td>25,00 %</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>8,00</td>
      <td>800,00</td>
      <td class="name?ajax_sent">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Sendt field is required." id="Collection_1__Sent" name="Collection[1].Sent" type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="Collection[1].Sent" type="hidden" value="false" />
      </td>
      <td class="name?ajax_payed">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Betalt field is required." id="Collection_1__Payed" name="Collection[1].Payed" type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="Collection[1].Payed" type="hidden" value="false" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I always find it useful to know why the issue is happening, instead of just finding a different solution. The other answer works by going to the row then getting all its cells. therefore by-passing your issue of using siblings. both works :)

Answer (score 0):

check below solution will fix your problem and make sure the siblings has class what you are expecting

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function () {
        var $parent = $(this).parent("td");
        var _invoice_id= $parent.siblings("td.name\\?ajax_invoice_id").html();

        var _payed="";
        if ($parent.hasClass("name?ajax_payed")) {
           _payed = this.checked;
        } else {
           _payed = $parent.siblings("td.name\\?ajax_payed").find("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked");
        }
        var _sent="";
        if ($parent.hasClass("name?ajax_sent")) {
           _sent = this.checked;
        } else {
           _sent = $parent.siblings("td.name\\?ajax_sent").find("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked");
        }




         alert('invoice_id: ' + _invoice_id + '\r\npayed: ' + _payed + '\r\nsent: ' + _sent);
    });
});
```

Comment: I copied your script but it's still the same - undefined on the checkbox which i click.

Comment: hmm i dont understand - still get undefined.. i tried with ie, ff and chrome. it works for you on the fiddle?

Comment: Yes it works fine for me... are you getting undefined in jsfiddle?

Comment: yeah. what the bloody.... oh well i found that i could use the eventarg and target value. Thanks for the help anyway though

Comment: we dont want to iterate over the siblings, check this solution https://jsfiddle.net/naveencgr/Lecbrhbd/2/